# Flutter file picker creates symlinks

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have battled this issue for sometime now and i seem to be going nowhere, I am using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) flutter plugin, its working on devices with android v7, now am running the app on emulator with android v9 and the filepicker creates symlink, here is a log:

```
I/FilePickerUtils( 7999): File loaded and cached at:/data/user/0/com.lulliezy.videostatus/cache/file_picker/KHALIGRAPH JONES x SARKODIE - WAVY (OFFICIAL VIDEO).webm
I/FilePickerDelegate( 7999): Absolute file path:/data/user/0/com.lulliezy.videostatus/cache/file_picker/KHALIGRAPH JONES x SARKODIE - WAVY (OFFICIAL VIDEO).webm
```

Now my understanding bt the word **cached** is a symlink is created, now how do i disable this feature or rather, get the original file name with this code:

```
await FilePicker.getFile(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['mp4', 'webm'],
);
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I should clarify, am using flutter ffmpeg so it complains with file does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a workaround for this, I copied the picked file to another temporary directory and used that new path after which when am done, I delete the copied file.